# Arranging the phenol derivative in decreasing order of acidity

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, aromatic-compounds

I am facing difficulty in the following problem.

> What is the decreasing order of acidity of the following phenol derivatives?
>
> [image: Phenols]

In my view benzene-1,2-diol **1** should be most acidic because $-\ce{OH}$ is a strong $-I$ group thereby it will stabilise the negative charge on oxygen formed after removal of a proton.

$\ce{OCH3}$ is a $+R$ and $-I$ group. Near the carbanion $-I$ effect should be more effective. Hence the second most acidic should be 2-methoxyphenol **2**. However the answer key gives it as 4-methoxyphenol **3**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The acidity order should be **1** > **2** > **3** as they have pKa values of 9.48, 9.98, and 10.21 respectively.

+R effect of $\ce{-OCH3}$ is more significant than +R effect of $\ce{-OH}$

In case of **1**, -I effect works at -ortho position and also +R effect works at -ortho position.

In case of **2**, -I effect works at -ortho position and also +R effect works at -ortho position. Net effect is +R effect as +R effect is dominant than -I effect.

In case of **3**, -I effect works at -para position and also +R effect works at -para position. Net effect is +R effect as +R effect is dominant than -I effect. But this +R effect is more dominant than in case **2** because -I effect is more dominant at -ortho position than at -para position but+R effect of equally effective at both -ortho and -para positions.

As a result of which, acidity is reduced to greater extent in the third compound compared to the second compound.

Comment: How do you know that +R effect is more dominant in case b).

Comment: If your assumption is taken as granted then would be the relative acidic strength of o-,m-,p-methoxy benzoic acid.this accordingly will be then m->o- > p-.

Comment: Yes. It is not I am saying for granted, it is general organic chemistry. Also +R effect is not meaningful at meso position.

Comment: Answer to the first comment, I have very clearly explained in my answer. Please read the answer very carefully

Comment: With regards to paragraphing, you need to press Enter twice to make a line break.

Comment: Hey Resorcinol, I wanted to know how to decide that a 5 memebered ring due to a H-bond was being formed or not in compounds A and B, as that would have reduced their acidity?