# Acidic strength of phenol derivatives

Tags: acid-base, phenols, nitro-compounds

While comparing the strengths of *o*-nitrophenol and *p*-nitrophenol, *p*-nitrophenol is found to be more acidic. The reason I studied for this is $\ce{H}$-bonding in *o*-nitrophenol which makes the acid more stable, making it a weak acid.

But between *o*-methoxyphenol and *p*-methoxyphenol, *o*-methoxyphenol is more acidic because of more -I effect at *o*-position. Doesn't $\ce{H}$-bonding happen here?

Can someone please clarify the exact reason for opposite orders?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arranging the phenol derivative in decreasing order of acidity](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/65157/arranging-the-phenol-derivative-in-decreasing-order-of-acidity)

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/71859/is-there-an-intramolecular-hydrogen-bond-in-guaiacol

Answer (score 0):

That's a really good question. The difference arises because -NO2 is -M group but -OCH3 is +M
So even if we think that the hydrogen of -OH group is doing Hydrogen bonding with OCH3 in the end the acidic strength will be decided by inductive effect of -OCH3 group at ortho and para position.
Since ortho is close its -I is dominating.
In NO2 it is a +I group so we didn't look at inductive